# Remove rows with "less than x rows" from Access pivot table or similar query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I managed to create a pivot table view in Access to get the rows into columns and selected the ones I need, but I want to remove from that report all rows with less than 5 courses and can't figure it out how. My data looks like this:

```
Company Student Course
ABC CP  S1
ABC CP  S2
ABC CP  S3
ABC CP  S4
ABC CP  S5
ABC JH  S1
ABC JH  S2
ABC JH  S3
ABC JH  S4
CBA HR  S1
CBA HR  S2
CBA HR  S3
CBA HR  S4
CBA HR  S5
```

The result I am looking is to get the following:

```
Company Student S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Total
ABC     CP      1   1   1   1   1   5
CBA     HR      1   1   1   1   1   5
```

In this case JH from Company ABC is not listed because has only 4 courses and not 5.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: [Have you triead anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am guessing that you mean Company Course Student not Company Student Course

Comment: is this homework?  try using a HAVING clause to remove rows with count(*) < 5

Comment: @Beth I am not sure that will work in MS Access

Comment: well, HAVING is the SQL syntax, if you're using the Query by example view, you'll need to change it to an aggregate query (hit the Sigma) and enter the criteria without returning the value (uncheck the Output box).  It will work in Access.  Is this homework?

Comment: @Beth I am fairly familiar with MS Access, I do not believe that will work. I am not the OP ;)

Comment: the idea is you apply the HAVING clause before the pivot.  Of course it's supported in Access.  You take your base query, create another query based on that one grouping by company/student where count(course) >= 5, then create another query based on those two joining on company/student, THEN pivot.  It's similar to the solution you posted below, except with persistent queries instead of SQL.

Comment: @Beth Yes, I am aware of that and replied based on such an idea over an hour before your comment. The point I was making is that you need such a derived table in MS Access. As yet, I do not know how it works in SQL Server.

Comment: my guess is it's a homework assignment and he's supposed to figure it out for himself.

Comment: @Beth Thanks for your feedback. It may seem like homework because I oversimplified the data to remove confidential information. I have a table with 40k records and 35 fields. I am new to Access and was trying to find a solution on how to remove the <5 from pivot table view that almost gave me the result I need. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to use a derived table:

```
TRANSFORM Count(c.course) AS countofcourse
SELECT c.company,
       c.course
FROM   courses c
       INNER JOIN (SELECT company,
                          course,
                          Count(course) AS CountOfCourse
                   FROM   courses
                   GROUP  BY company,
                             course
                   HAVING Count(course) > 4) cc
               ON ( c.course = cc.course )
                  AND ( c.company = cc.company )
GROUP  BY c.company,
          c.course
PIVOT c.student;
```

Comment: you wanted to group on company/student to count courses?

Comment: @Beth According to the OP, it is courses per company that is relevant.

Comment: @Fionnuala I'll try your suggestion. And you are correct, I need to find out how many courses have each individual and company.